# Does spring hibernate lock apply to other threads on different machines?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, locking

```
HibernateTemplate().refresh(obj, LockMode.UPGRADE);
```

Will above line block all threads including the threads on a different machine from continuing execution?

Also when will this lock be released?

Is it at the end of hibernate session?

How expensive to getting the lock and wake up existing threads when lock is released? 
Thanks

Comment: Additionally, if obj has foreign reference to other entities(tables), will all other table rows are locked too? Since the lock is at the db, I assume all processes (even on different machines) will be blocked if they try to acquire lock on the same obj (but obj is not the same as one row in db. It can be complicated by foreign table reference )

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate lock requests are delegated to the database, so no in-memory Java locking will happen.

The `LockMode.Upgrade` is [equivalent to PESSIMISTIC_WRITE](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/), meaning that an exclusive lock is taken on the associated database row.

The current lock will prevent other transactions from acquiring a shared/exclusive lock for this particular row, until your current transaction ends (commit or rollback).

If other threads don't require to take this particular database row lock, then no contention will occur.

Threads are not waken up, like it happens in Java. A database process waiting for a lock, will never get to sleep. You can configure a time interval for the lock acquisition too.